# How to arrange the colored cells in game grid?

Tags: mathematics, optimization, puzzle-creation, graph-theory, reference-request

**Puzzle:** In a game grid some cells are missing. Each line has only one colored cell with a label (a number greater than zero). This is an example grid and the number of columns/rows can be less than the colored cell:

[image: ![enter image description here]

All numbers in the grid are for example.

A player can only move a colored cell in a horizontal direction. When all cells of the same color are placed in one column a reduction factor is applied to the numerical labels, and (vice versa) if such a position is violated the initial label values ​​are restored. The factor is different for each color.

The player's task is to arrange the colored cells so that the sum of all labels is minimal. In the final solution the sum of labels in one column for cells of different colors cannot exceed a certain value. This value can be different for each column.

I have a practical application of the task above and I want to formulate a puzzle for the first time. I am looking for some similar tasks, because for now I can't formulate an optimization task.

**Edit**
I have read the paper [Connected bin packing problem on traceable graphs](https://ijnao.um.ac.ir/article_40635.html) and looking for a graph approach.

Some very interesting [procedures for the bin packing problem with precedence constraints](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0377221715009741?casa_token=J2HTjTsuynQAAAAA:49eFv7o-_Nk1Tgpy7PyCeQ5KCjGad04-SQtsOyadYo6W2h7GBSLhNGHGgT5QvZKpC5b3sn4b9A) are discussed in the paper.

**Question:** Is it possible to find the optimal solution to the proposed puzzle?

Comment: What are the restrictions in moving the colored cells?

Comment: @justhalf, just moving on left/right in one line

Comment: What's preventing me from just putting each color on different columns, which would be optimal as per my current understanding of this question?

Comment: It has shades of the binpacking problem. If you ignore the colors and reduction factor they bring, and have tight limits for the column totals, and have each row be the same length, then it is pretty much the [Multiway number partitioning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiway_number_partitioning). Since that is an NP-hard problem, it is unlikely that there is a efficient algorithm that solves it in general. This is true for many logic puzzle types, even Sudoku, so small instances may well make for interesting puzzles solvable by logic rather than brute force.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis, thank you for comment. I have read some papers about multiway number partitioning and found an idea to map game grid into a graph object

Comment: I have a mixed integer linear programming formulation, but your example instance is infeasible.  For example, you cannot place even the two green 3s without violating the column upper bounds.

Comment: @RobPratt, thank you for comment. Upper bounds and another numbers just for example. What is your formulation?

Answer (score 1):

You can solve the problem via mixed integer linear programming as follows.

Let $I$ be the set of rows, $J$ the set of columns, and $C$ the set of colors.  For $c\in C$, let $J_c \subseteq J$ be the set of columns that can contain color $c$.  For $i\in I$, let $c_i$ and $\ell_i$ be the color and initial label, respectively, for row $i$.  For $c\in C$, let $f_c$ be the reduction factor for color $c$.  For $j\in J$, let $u_j$ be the upper bound for the sum of final values in column $j$.

For $i\in I$ and $j\in J$, let binary decision variable $x_{i,j}$ indicate whether cell $(i,j)$ is occupied.  (To avoid the missing cells, either fix $x_{i,j}=0$ for those cells or use a sparse index set for non-missing cells $(i,j)$.)  For $c \in C$ and  $j\in J_c$, let binary decision variable $y_{c,j}$ indicate whether all labels for color $c$ appear in column $j$.  For $i\in I$ and $j\in J$, let continuous decision variable $z_{i,j}$ be the final value ($0$ if unoccupied) in cell $(i,j)$.

The problem is to
minimize $$\sum_{i \in I} \sum_{j\in J} z_{i,j}$$
subject to
\begin{align}
\sum_{j \in J} x_{i,j} &= 1
&& \text{for $i \in I$} \tag1 \\
y_{c,j} &\le x_{i,j}
&& \text{for $c \in C, j \in J_c, i \in I: c_i = c$} \tag2 \\
z_{i,j} &= \ell_i (x_{i,j} - (1 - f_{c_i}) y_{c_i,j})
&& \text{for $i\in I, j \in J$} \tag3 \\
\sum_{i \in I} z_{i,j} &\le u_j
&& \text{for $j \in J$} \tag4
\end{align}
Constraint $(1)$ selects exactly one column for the label in each row.
Constraint $(2)$ forces all labels with color $c$ to be in column $j$ if $y_{c,j}=1$.
Constraint $(3)$ determines the final value of cell $(i,j)$ based on $x$ and $y$.
Constraint $(4)$ enforces the upper bound on column $j$.